# How to close CSS3 Lightbox by clicking outside of the current image?

Tags: css, image-gallery

I try to close lightbox by clicking outside of the current image, but I don't how to do.
I just have a link "Back" in order to close this lightbox...

*I use only CSS3, maybe Script is the solution, thanks for your help.*

Here's a short CSS :

```
/*thumbnails*/
    .album {
       position: relative;
       width:1200px;
       height:auto;
       float: left;
     } 


/*fullscreen*/
    .overlay { 
       position: fixed;
       left: 258px;
       top: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
       overflow: hidden;
    } 

/*close fullscreen, back to thumbnails*/
    .close { 
       position: absolute;
       top: 50px;
       left: 50%;
    }
```

HTML

```
<ul class="album">
    <li>
       <a href="example"><img src="images/thumbs/example.jpg></a>
          <div class="overlay" id="example">
            <img src="images/full/example.jpg" />
                <a href="#" class="close">BACK</a>
          </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pseudo-element on the `.close` element and position that between the lightbox and the image using `z-index`.

```
.overlay:target .close:before {
    position: fixed;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

.overlay { z-index: 5; }
.lightbox image { z-index: 15; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, seems to work but not entirely. In fact, I can close by clicking outside the current image (that's great !) but there's a problem, it can't go back to the thumbnails, it seems to stuck on the "close" content.

Comment: @jason-b I don’t know your HTML, so it is a little hard to find the problem…

Comment: Just editing my HTML, if it can help you to help me ^^

Comment: @jason-b `.overlay:target` sould do the job…

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention it's working, great :)